# Como gravar no banco um array de quantidades e tamanhos referentes ao cadastro de um produto? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho uma crud onde cadastro o produto, dentro desse cadastro tenho um modal onde é possível informar os tamanhos e quantidades referentes ao produto que estou cadastrando, depois esse modal me retorna um array de tamanhos e um array de quantidades nesse caso, poderia fazer um foreach para inserir no banco de dados.. até aí tudo bem, mas eu quero armazenar os tamanhos e quantidades na minha tabela ESTOQUE, onde tenho os seguintes campos

```
id | item | quantidade | tamanho
```

como eu faço pra saber o código do item que vou gravar nessa tabela, pois vou estar cadastrando o item em questão, mesmo que eu execute primeiro a query que grava na tabela de produtos teria alguma forma de buscar o id do último item inserido no banco ou algo nesse sentido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vou tentar organizar melhor as coisas, pois a sua explicação não ficou muito clara pelo menos para mim.

Digamos que temos uma tabela de **produtos** primeiro:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtos` (
  `ID_PRODUTO` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DESCRICAO` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PRODUTO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Esse produto possui por sua vez várias quantidade e tamanhos. Existem algumas abordagens ao redor dessa questão, eu poderia ter por exemplo um campo TEXT nessa tabela de produtos para armazenar esse array em JSON por exemplo, mas não existe um campo do tipo Array no MySQL, isso geralmente é encontrado em banco de dados NoSQL, como é o caso do MongoDB.

Sabendo disso vamos precisar criar uma nova tabela com a ligação desse produto com suas quantidade e tamanhos. Logo teremos uma tabela **produtos_tamanhos_quantidades**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtos_tamanhos_quantidades` (
  `ID_PRODUTO_TAMANHO_QUANTIDADE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_PRODUTO` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TAMANHO` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `QUANTIDADE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PRODUTO_TAMANHO_QUANTIDADE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Vale lembrar não estou criando nenhuma **Foreign Key** aqui, mas poderia ser facilmente adicionada, ligando a tabela de tamanhos e quantidade com a tabela de produtos.

Diante disso ao gravar o produto na tabela de produtos, você em seguida vai percorrer o seu array de quantidades e tamanhos inserindo uma linha para cada tamanho e quantidade na tabela "**produtos_tamanhos_quantidades**". Um exemplo básico em PHP ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    $conecta = mysql_connect("HOST", "LOGIN", "SENHA") or print (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("BANCO", $conecta) or print(mysql_error());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (DESCRICAO) VALUES ('Caixa de Papelão')"; 
    mysql_query($sql, $conecta);

    $idProdutoInserido = mysql_insert_id();

    $tamanhosQuantidade = array('15cm' => 30, '30cm' => 50, '45cm' => 20);

    foreach($tamanhosQuantidade as $key => $value){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO produtos_tamanhos_quantidades (ID_PRODUTO, TAMANHO, QUANTIDADE) VALUES (" . $idProdutoInserido . ", '" . $key . "', $value)"; 
        mysql_query($sql, $conecta);
    }
?>
```

No código acima conectamos com o banco, executamos o insert de um produto na tabela, e em seguida pegamos o ID que o MySQL gerou para aquele produto. Em seguida criei um array de exemplo com tamanhos e quantidades, percorri esse array através do comando **foreach**, realizando um insert para cada tamanho.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! era isso que eu precisava mesmo.

Comment: De nada, fico feliz de ter ajudado!